# GUI & Script Integration

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I want to create an executable file with pyinstaller and for this I've a script with a GUI that is supposed to launch when executed. It grabs users inputs and executes the bot script. I've run both the bot script and the GUI script separately and they work as I want them to, however when trying to integrate the two so that the input of the GUI gets sent to the bot, I ran into issues. The bot function gets called right away as I run the script, without even showing the user interface.

```
from instabot import Bot
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import datetime
import re
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import shutil
import tkinter as tk

# GUI
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Confessions Bot")
window.geometry("600x300")
window.grid_columnconfigure((0,2), weight = 1)

label_tell_account = tk.Label(window, text = "Tellonym Account")
label_tell_password = tk.Label(window, text = "Tellonym Password")
label_ig_account = tk.Label(window, text = "Instagram Account")
label_ig_password = tk.Label(window, text = "Instagram Password")

tell_account = tk.Entry(window)
tell_password = tk.Entry(window)
ig_account = tk.Entry(window)
ig_password = tk.Entry(window)
run = tk.Button(text = "Run!", command = bot(tell_account.get(), tell_password.get(), ig_account.get(), ig_password.get()))

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png"))
tk.Label(window, image = image).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_tell_account.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
tell_account.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_tell_password.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
tell_password.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_ig_account.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
ig_account.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_ig_password.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
ig_password.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
run.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

window.mainloop()
def bot(tell_account_input, tell_password_input, ig_account_input, ig_password_input):
    # Getting Tells to Post
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://tellonym.me/login?redirect=/tells")

    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys(tell_account_input)

    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys(tell_password_input)

    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()

    for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rmq-f5f56a03"))):
         unclean_name = re.findall("element\s*=\s*([\S\s]+)", str(element))
         name = re.sub('[^\w]', '', str(unclean_name))
         element.screenshot("to_post/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p") + str(name) + ".png")

    for i in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rmq-f5f56a03"))):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rmq-f5f56a03"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "answer"))).send_keys("posted")
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()

    driver.quit()

    # Pic Formating
    for pics in os.listdir("to_post/"):
        image = Image.open("to_post/" + pics, 'r')
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image = image.crop(((1, 1, 600, 50)))
        template = Image.open("template.jpg")
        template.paste(image, (85,380))
        template.save(re.sub(".png", ".jpg", str("to_post/" + pics)))

    for item in os.listdir("to_post/"):
         if item.endswith(".png"):
             os.remove(os.path.join("to_post/", item))

    # Posting Tells to Instagram
    bot = Bot()

    bot.login(username = ig_account_input,
            password = ig_password_input)

    for pics in os.listdir("to_post/"):
        bot.upload_photo("to_post/" + str(pics), caption = "test")

    # Movig pics from to_post folder -> posted
    for pics in os.listdir("to_post/"):
        shutil.move("to_post/" + pics, "posted")
        os.rename("posted/" + pics, "posted/" + re.sub(".REMOVE_ME", "", str(pics)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are calling bot function while passing it to argument `command`.

```
run = tk.Button(text = "Run!", command = bot(tell_account.get(), tell_password.get(), ig_account.get(), ig_password.get()))
```

This is the line invoking bot function. You should use lambda expression
when you need to call a function with arguments.

Try this:

```
run = tk.Button(text = "Run!", command = lambda : bot(tell_account.get(), tell_password.get(), ig_account.get(), ig_password.get()))
```